# setInterval only runs once on object method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, setinterval

Here is the code.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.testfunc = function() {

        this.init = function() {
            setInterval(this.func1(), 1000);
        };

        this.func1 = function() {
            console.log('func1');
            this.func2();
        };

        this.func2 = function() {
            console.log('func2');
            //some codes
        };

        return this.init();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

*When I use parenthesis the 1st and 2nd method runs but the 1st method is called only once.

*When I don't use parenthesis the 1st method runs in interval just fine but it doesn't/couldn't call the 2nd method.

What should I go with? With parenthesis or not? I need to run the 1st method in the interval but also need to call 2nd method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` expects a function. `this.func1` is a function but `this.func1()` is the result of calling the function, which is `undefined` (the function doesn't return anything). This is your first misunderstanding.

The second misunderstanding has to do with scope. If you call `setInterval(this.func1, 1000);` then `setInterval` will call the correct function, but `this` will not refer to what you think. I don't have time now to explain and you should definitely read more about this. In any case, this will work:

```
this.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function() { self.func1(); }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Works awesome thanks! So does this mean that I'm also passing the reference of `this`?

Comment: In a way. `this` is the context of the function. If I call `self.func2()` then `this` in `func2` will refer to `self` which ultimately refers to `$.fn.testfunc` which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because when you use `setInterval`, the first argument must be a reference to a funcion:

```
setInterval(this.func1, 1000);
```

It's without parentheses because `this.func1()` means that function `this.func1` is executed. And `this.func1` is the name of the function, which you can use as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

With parentheses, you're invoking the method, not setting it as a callback.

`setInterval(this.func1(), 1000);`

func1 won't be executed in the scope of `this`, so it won't have access to func2. I'm a bit rusty, but you should be able to use call(). I don't recall if you need to call() from init and func1, or just within func1.