# SetInterval calling method using .call(this) calls it only once

Tags: javascript, setinterval, function-calls

Hello I am completely new to JavaScript and I am trying to do something , but I can't understand when I call this function:

```
this.start = function () {
    this.interval = setInterval(startIncrement.call(this) , 1000);
}
```

*startIncrement* only executes  once. I am trying to do Counter class that generates two buttons(start and stop) and one textbox.So when I do:

```
var a = new Counter(); // generates object of Counter
a.init(); // generates the HTML (did that part)
a.start(); //start increasing the value of text box over period of time
a.stop(); // stops the counting (did that part)
```

And buttons start and stop simply have onclick event that call start and stop methods of Counter. I tried all answers of this question [setInterval only runs once on object method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923180/setinterval-only-runs-once-on-object-method) but it didn't work and now I am stuck.

Comment: The first answer to that question is the answer to your question: setInterval expects a function to be passed to it, and you're passing the result of calling your "startIncrement" function. Perhaps you meant `.bind()` instead of `.call()`.

Comment: Yes, now that you say it like that it makes total sense , but sadly I don't know when to use call , bind or apply I've read about them , but I seem to be misusing them.. could you explain to me how they works if you have the time? Thanks in advance. P.S I already asked spender to do so , but if you want you can do it too :)

Comment: Well @spender explained `.bind()` which is the only one of  the three that gives you back a function to use later. Both `.call()` and `.apply()` are ways to invoke a function immediately; they're different in detail but they do basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `.call` method of a function invokes it immediately, with the (first) parameter becoming `this` to the contents of the function.

By using

```
setInterval(startIncrement.call(this) , 1000);
```

you're calling the `startIncrement` method immediately and using whatever it returns as a parameter to `setInterval`. Unless it returns a function, that's not what you want.

Did you mean:

```
setInterval(startIncrement.bind(this) , 1000);
```

?

`.bind` will hand you back a function that, *when you call it*, is assured to have the (first) parameter as the `this` object. It does not invoke the function. It creates a new function that wraps around the original function, doing a small amount of work to change the `this` object when it calls the original function that it wraps.

Comment: YES! I must have misunderstood the functions .. in fact could you explain me more about apply,call and bind because I've been reading for them for one hour and I seem to be using them unproperly.. if you have time of course.